# Spectral theorem over $\mathbb {R}$

Tags: linear-algebra, diagonalization

It is clear to me that a self-adjoint linear map on a real/complex inner product space has real eigenvalues, and its eigenspaces for distinct eigenvalues are orthogonal.

In order to prove it is diagonalisable, we also need that the geometric multiplicity of the eigenspaces equals the algebraic multiplicity. How is this done?

In particular, if the arguments differ, how is this demonstrated over $\mathbb{R}$? I have seen proofs over $\mathbb {C}$, and they use algebraic closure, so I imagine the real case is more involved, and would like to see a proof that works here.

Comment: I can see that you would be able to pass to the complexification of your space and use spectral theorem from $\mathbb {C}$. Follow ups would then be, prove the eigenvectors are (can be taken as) real. Furthermore, if there is a way to do this natively (without algebraic closure), and it isn't too painful, I'd like to see that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By induction. Let $T$ be a real self-adjoint endomorphism of a real IPS, $V$. Let $\lambda$ be an eigenvalue of $T$ since $T$ is self-adjoint, $T$ has a real eigenvalue. Then by definition, there is a $\lambda$-eigenvector $v$ for $T$. Let $V'=\{v\}^\perp$. Then since $T$ is self-adjoint, if $w\in V'$, then $\langle Tw,v\rangle = \langle w,Tv\rangle=\langle w,\lambda v\rangle= 0$. Thus $V'$ is $T$-invariant. Hence $V$ splits as a direct sum $\Bbb{R}v\oplus V'$ and $T$ splits with it as $T=\lambda \oplus T|_{V'}$. Then by induction $T|_{V'}$ has an orthonormal basis of eigenvectors, and together with $v$, these give an orthonormal basis for $V$ consisting of eigenvectors of $T$.

This argument doesn't depend on the base field being $\Bbb{R}$ or $\Bbb{C}$, but I assumed it was $\Bbb{R}$ to make the writing simpler.

Comment: Nice. As a note, the claim that $T$ has a real eigenvalue follows from passing to the complexification of $V$, using algebraic closure of $\mathbb{C}$, and then using the fact that there its eigenvalues are real, and that complexifying doesn't change the eigenvalues, yes?

Comment: @JoshuaTilley Oh yes, sorry.